# How to implement scrollViewDidScroll: method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I'm building an article reading app.List of articles is in `UITableViewController`,I'm facing an issue when i use `scrollViewDidScroll:` method first cell of table is display under the `UINavigationBar`.
But when commented this code it displays fine means first cell exactly after the `UINavigationBar`.

here is my code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scroll {
    // UITableView only moves in one direction, y axis

    CGFloat currentOffset = scroll.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat maximumOffset = scroll.contentSize.height - scroll.frame.size.height;

    // Change 10.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
    if (maximumOffset - currentOffset  <= -60.0) {
        x++;
        [self LoadMore];

        [self.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{

        }];

        [self.tableView reloadData];    
    }
}
```

Comment: Check for your maximumOffset value. Maybe your logic in scrollViewDidScroll method is reducing your tableView y-axis

Comment: @ walle84 thanks,i have used to print the value of maximumOffset it gives 2072 and it increases on scroll.

Comment: @ Walle84,i'm new to iOS development could you help me to correct my logic.

Comment: Firstly why u need scrollViewDidScroll method for?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not be the solution to your problem. This is to point out a major flow in your code that could be the cause of your problem.

You should not reload data `[self LoadMore];[self.tableView reloadData];`  directly inside `scrollViewDidScroll:` method. This will cause the method to be called multiple times as you scroll.

And I think you have implemented infinite loading incorrectly.

This code should be placed inside some initializer method (e.g., viewDidLoad)

```
[tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
    [self LoadMore];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    // call [tableView.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating] when done
}];
```

If you are planing to load more items as you scroll, I don't think you need to use `scrollViewDidScroll:` at all. Simply put the above code inside `viewDidLoad:` and everything should work. You will have to keep track of the number of items loaded separately. Hope this will help. :)